# How can I prevent ClickJacking Attacks using X-Frame-Options Headers

Tags: asp.net, security, iframe, x-frame-options, clickjacking

Currently, I am assessing the Vulnerability of one of the websites and one of the points I am looking at is how can I prevent my website from potential clickjacking attacks?

I am no expert in this domain, but I have a few observations so far,

1. Missing X-Frame-Options header means that this website could be at
   risk of a clickjacking attack.
2. The X-Frame-Options HTTP header field
   indicates a policy that specifies whether the browser should render
   the transmitted resource within a frame or an iframe.
3. Servers can declare this policy in the header of their HTTP responses to prevent
   clickjacking attacks.

As I said, I am no expert in this field so looking forward to hear some ideas of how can I use X-Frame-Options header from preventing clickjacking attacks?

Answer (score 0):

you can rely on security header `X-Frame-Options` to indicate to the browser not to render any iframe.

this can used by sending a response header `X-Frame-Options: DENY` or
`X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` if you want to use iframes but only for pages that are in the same origin as your page.

Comment: Where can I define this X-Frame-Options in my aspx pages?

Comment: you add it somewhere in 
`
Application_BeginRequest() {
    Response.AddHeader("X-Frame-Options", "DENY");
}`

Comment: I am using web forms. So where can I find Application_BeginRequest?

Comment: you can add it in you `Global.asax.cs` file as follow
```protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.AddHeader("X-Frame-Options", "DENY");
 }```

Comment: Thank you so much. With this been added, it will add the header with every request made?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Header always set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
</IfModule>
```

You can get the more details of X-Frame-Options on below
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

You can add below snippet code on last of your server .htaccess file and test the site on https://clickjacker.io/test.

Comment: I have tried your code and added in the .htaccess file but I am getting the Internal Server Error